# @Url.Action and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I want `@Url.Action()` to redirect to a method of a controller with parameters that will be used in a JavaScript function.

The parameters are two, `id = item.LevelId`, that I take it from the `foreach` of the table, and the second one is `annoLectivoId = "parm1"`. I need that `annoLectivoId` have the value of the variable `Anno`, from JavaScript.

I've tried `this.href = this.href.replace(3, Anno);` but it doesn't worked.

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeStatus", "Enroll_Student", new { id = item.LevelId, annoLectivoId = 3 })"
    title="ver detalle" style="color:red" 
    onclick="FunctionCall()">
   detalle
 </a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function FunctionCall() {
    var Anno = document.getElementById("AnnoLectivoId").value;

    this.href = this.href.replace(3, Anno);
}
```

Comment: why are you firing two events at same time? there is onclick method also there is a href? can you explain why?

Comment: your id in the url action is not what you are looking for in your getelementbyid call

Comment: I tried all, @Url action original is `@Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "ChangeStatus", "Enroll_Student", new { id = item.LevelId, AnnoLectivo = "param1" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info Detalle"})`

Comment: still same problem.  Your getElementById is looking for AnnoLectivoId as the ID of the anchor.  <a id="AnnoLectivold" ...>  but it appears to me that you are setting the id to something else (id = item.LevelId).  Anno in your script will not find your element since it's ID is not AnnoLectivoId...

Comment: getElementById is looking for AnnoLectivoId this is a DropDownList : ` @Html.DropDownList("AnnoLectivoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" , @id = "AnnoLectivoId" })` in javascript I can to have the value `var Anno` but i don't know how I can pass the value to the variable `annoLectivoId` in `@Url.Action`

Comment: UrlHelper.Action only generates a URL. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve with this code.